# Using the result of an outer query in a subquery or similar

Tags: mysql

I have a devices table that contains a device_id and an account_id.
Every time a new device is created in the device table, a new table with the name 'd_' . $device_id is created.

The idea was to store the flood of data created by a device in a separate table. To prevent an excessive growth of a single table.
This design scheme is now blowing up in my face.

- devices table

> id, device_id, account_id

- d_$device_id table (The table is composed of d_ and the device_id from the devices table!)

> timestamp, value1, value2, value3

Now I would like to generate the following query with this schema to retrieve all devices belonging to an account, but additionally also the newest line from the 'd_' . $device_id table.

My approach is as follows. The problem is that the table of the subquery must be variable, for clarification: 'd_' . $s1.device_id

```
SELECT * FROM `devices` s1, (SELECT * FROM `d_` . $s1.device_id ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1) s2 WHERE s1.account_id = 2;
```

I'm afraid my design idea doesn't work that way, but maybe someone here has a solution for that.

Comment: What **exactly** is not working yet? Is this really a PHP problem?

Comment: No, it's more of a SQL design/query issue.

Comment: Feel free to add all clarification to your question by editing it. If this is not a PHP problem, please remove the tag

Comment: Tag was removed. Sorry. I hope the paraphrase of the problem is understandable, I wouldn't know how to describe it more precisely.

Comment: *a new table with the name 'd_' . $device_id is created* Why? A `Devices` table and `Device_Id` column would be the correct approach, you should re-design your database. Storing data in tables is the one the your RDBMS is designed to do, when done correctly you can have millions or billions or rows.

Comment: The reason why I create a new table d_device_id for each device is described. I want to prevent that a single table contains the telemetry data of all devices. The table would grow by 40,320 rows per device every month. With 100 devices this would be over 48 million rows per year.

Comment: I understand the concern, the alternative you've given yourself is the requirement to always have to use dynamic SQL and you cannot easily perform queries or analysis over multiple devices, eg counting. 48m rows is no problem for a good RDBMS, one of our production system's logs receives about 250-300 rows per minute on average, almost 24/7, it has over a billion rows, it's partitioned on date and with good indexes performance is no problem.

Comment: @Stu Thanks for your answer. I will adapt my database design and follow your approaches.

Answer (score -1):

You can query for the table then continue if it returns a value

```
DECLARE @deviceTable nvarchar(50)
DECLARE @query nvarchar(max);

SELECT @deviceTable = [TABLE_NAME]
FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_NAME = ''+$s1.device_id+''
IF @deviceTable IS NOT NULL OR LEN(@deviceTable) > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @query = 'SELECT * FROM [DEVICES] s1, (SELECT * FROM '+@deviceTable+'+ ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1) s2 WHERE s1.account_id = 2;'
        EXEC sp_executesql @query
    END
```

EDIT:

```
PREPARE query FROM 'SELECT * FROM [DEVICES] s1, (SELECT * FROM ? ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1) s2 WHERE s1.account_id = 2;';
Set @deviceTable = SELECT TABLE_NAME
    FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = ''+@somedeviceidhere+''
EXECUTE query using @deviceTable;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE query;
```

Comment: The OP has tagged MySql